# PostgreSQL generate month and year series based on table field and fill with nulls if no data for a given month

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

I want to generate series of month and year from the next month of current year(say, `start_month`) to 12 months from `start_month` along with the corresponding data (if any, else return nulls) from another table in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT ( ( DATE '2019-03-01' + ( interval '1' month * generate_series(0, 11) ) ) 
         ::  DATE ) dd, 
       extract(year FROM ( DATE '2019-03-01' + ( interval '1' month * 
                                                 generate_series(0, 11) ) 
                         )), 
       coalesce(SUM(price), 0) 
FROM   items 
WHERE  s.date_added >= '2019-03-01' 
       AND s.date_added < '2020-03-01' 
       AND item_type_id = 3 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2 
ORDER  BY 2;
```

The problem with the above query is that it is giving me the same value for `price` for all the months. The requirement is that the `price` column be filled with nulls or zeros if no `price` data is available for a given month.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54758779/edit) your question and add some sample rows from `items` table and the expected output, in **text** format only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `generate_series()` in the `FROM` clause.  You are summarizing the data -- i.e. calculating the price over the entire range -- and then projecting this on all months.  Instead:

```
SELECT gs.yyyymm,
       coalesce(SUM(i.price), 0) 
FROM generate_series('2019-03-01'::date, '2020-02-01', INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
                    ) gs(yyyymm) LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON gs.yyyymm = DATE_TRUNC('month', s.date_added) AND
       i.item_type_id = 3 
GROUP BY gs.yyyymm
ORDER BY gs.yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked. However, I had to edit the query a little.

`SELECT gs.yyyymm::date,
       coalesce(SUM(i.price), 0) 
FROM generate_series('2019-03-01'::date, '2020-02-01', INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
                    ) gs(yyyymm) LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON gs.yyyymm = DATE_TRUNC('month', i.date_added) AND
     i.item_type_id = 3 
GROUP BY gs.yyyymm
ORDER BY 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You want `generate_series` in the `FROM` clause and join with it, somewhat like

```
SELECT months.m::date, ...
FROM generate_series(
        start_month,
        start_month + INTERVAL '11 months',
        INTERVAL '1 month'
     ) AS months(m)
   LEFT JOIN items
      ON months.m::date = items.date_added
```